# Hide <noscript> contents from google and other search engines

Tags: seo, search-engines, content, cloaking

I've got some content wrapped into `<noscript>` tag which I don't want google and any other search engines to see, is there a way to hide it?

Comment: Why are you trying to hide that content from Google?

Answer (score 2):

No your way off. [Noscript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/noscript) is a tag to be used when someone visit's your page that is not using JavaScript.

For example:

```
 <script>
     \\ I am a awesome javascript
 </script>
 <noscript>
 <p>You do not have JavaScript enabled so you can't use our awesome JavaScript</p>
 </noscript>
```

So in the above example people with JavaScript enabled would execute the awesome JavaScript, Those people without JavaScript would see a message on the page which is obvious from what I put.

What you are looking for is a way of serving content based on IP and user agent, this is refereed to as [cloaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking) and will most likely get your site smashed off the face of the earth and I strongly recommend you do not proceed as Google and other search engines are forever catching people out doing this since the day people first started doing it.

If you want pages not to appear in the index then you want to use robots.txt and noindex on your pages, but bare in mind this doesn't stop Google crawling your pages it means they don;t index it into the public.

Comment: Are you saying that noscript is harmful for sep? How come big sites, like stackechange use it and still get good rankings? I'm bit confused

Comment: No, I'm saying noscript doesn't hide content from Google.

Comment: Oh sorry for misunderstanding, the question I wanted to ask is, is there a way to hide contents of <noscript>, or in fact hide whole <noscript> block from google, so it doesn't see it?

Comment: yes, there is but this is classed as cloaking.... you should never hide any content from Google other than using noindex, and robots. Google will slap your site... Please re-read my answer. it says this.

Answer (score 0):

@bybe let me clear that the hiding content from search engine using any technique is not cloaking.

Cloaking is; to show different version of your website to search engine and another version of same page to your website visitors.

@llya Knaup

I am not getting your exact question of hiding javascript, but i am trying to summarize the whole scenario.

See, there is no harm in hiding block or some content on website until your motive is to provide better web usability to your website visitors.

For example: Your website having some block of content that will be only visible when someone clicks on a readmore link or button. Now, it is not hard to hide that content using display:none or visible:false as a default as you are showing that content only if visitors want to read it.

I hope you understand my point...

Comment: 10 years ago maybe, nowadays no... Unless its content that requires authentication it is considered cloaking to detect bots and present different data than a normal visitor

Comment: Not 10 years ago..i think you should checkout this Google webmaster guidelines to learn more about Cloaking !! http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66355

Comment: I am fully aware of what cloaking is, and I'm fully aware of all the information provided on that page... display:none, noscript and most javascript does `NOT` hide content from search engines. Your mistaken what the person has asked.. He wants to HIDE content from search engines, not the user... Display:none simply hides it from the user, search engines see elements in display:none and even index them as well as javascript and most ajax content.. And again, hiding content from Google which can be processed though algorithms is cloaking, unless noindex, robots, or authentication is used.